# OpenSSL req won't work on PHP Shell

Tags: php, openssl

I've been searching for the solution of my problem which is about OpenSSL. I'm using shell_exec() to run shell promts. For example:

`shell_exec("openssl genrsa -out myprvkey.pem 1024");` works fine, and generates myprvkey.pem.

However,

`shell_exec("openssl req -new -key myprvkey.pem -x509 -days 365 -out mypubcert.pem");` isn't working without giving any errors.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks. PS: Please remind me if I'm missing something.

OpenSSL Version: 268439647

Comment: No writing permissions for the `www` / `apache` / etc. user?

Comment: I've checked it. Gave myprvkey.pem 777 and still not working.

Comment: You could switch to `exec()` and capture the output using the second parameter. Perhaps that gives you more information. And giving private keys `777` permissions is a very bad idea.

Comment: @jeroen i've gave it 777 to test if the problem was about writing permissions. tried exec() with output, gave nothing.

Comment: @jeroen is it possible to give error because not having configuration file.

Comment: I don't know. You could try so `su` to the web-server user and see if you can run the script that way from the command line.

Comment: Have you considered using `openssl_pkey_new` and `openssl_pkey_get_public()` [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create a CSR? If so you can do so using [phpseclib, a pure PHP CSR implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html), pretty easily. Here's an example that creates a new RSA key and a new CSR:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($privKey->createKey());
$privKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$x509->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');

$csr = $x509->signCSR();

echo $x509->saveCSR($csr);
?>
```

Here's an example that creates a new CSR utilizing an existing RSA key:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$privKey->loadKey('...');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$x509->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');

$csr = $x509->signCSR();

echo $x509->saveCSR($csr);
?>
```

(the only diff is that `loadKey` is being passed a string [which could be populated via `file_get_contents` or just directly inputted] instead of the output of `extract($rsa->createKey())`)

Comment: it creates CERTIFICATE REQUEST but the thing we want is CERTIFICATE . Is it possible too?

Comment: @WalkerJetBat - it is. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/guide.html for more info.